# How would you write this function in python?

Tags: python, function, math

in a subject for a class I need to create a plot of various functions like:  ∗ 2(), converting them to something like this:  `n * np.log2(n)`

The following one is giving me some problems:  ∗  ∗ 10() on 1 <=  <= 9

I have to call the function and give (n) as an argument but I don´t know how to represent that one.

I am editing this question because I wasn´t very clear.
I have a function where I need to convert text equations to python euquations like stated above:

```
def plot_funs(xs):

    js0 = [x**2+2 for x in xs]
    js1 = [x + np.log2(x) for x in xs]
    js1_b = [t*x*np.log10(x) for x in xs]
    yjs2 = [3 + np.log2(6*x) + x for x in xs]
```

Then the function is ploted. If the t is ignored, it would return something like this:

[image]

But the problem is that i don´t know how to plot the t mentioned above.

This exercise is focusing on studying the function growths if that helps.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is fixed ? You can't plot a line on  a 2D whart with 2 unknows variabl, please clarify

Comment: @azro What's a "2D whart"?

Comment: chart sorry, that's unclear what represent the xAxis and what would make mulitple line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried, and what are you stuck on exactly? See [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341), plus [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you manage to plot `n log2(n)`? Can you please show us the code, and the image? Then we can think about how to modify that to add the `t` in there.

Comment: I added the image with the other functions plotted.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an input from the user by `input()`, and construct the `t` vector as `np.arange()`, then write the equation and plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('Enter value for n:')
n = int(input())
t = np.arange(1,n+0.01,0.01)
f = t * n * np.log10(n)

plt.plot(t,f)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I'm guessing it was because from the OP's question it really sounds like `n` is the variable, and `t` is a parameter. But your answer makes it the other way around, with `n` being a parameter and `t` the variable. Of course it's hard to say for sure since the OP's question was not very explicit about that.

Comment: The requested equation says ** ∗  ∗ 10() on 1 <=  <= 9**, which could imply that `t` is an independent variable, whereas `n` is a parameter. For example, you can plot `f(t)` against `t` for different values of `n`. Anyway, the OP wasn't so clear, so it still is my own understanding. Thanks for sharing your thought.